# How To Make raw_input Not A String In python

Tags: python-2.7, raw-input

I want to make this program do the summation of something with their input. My code thus far

```
def summation():
start = int(raw_input("Start value of n?: "))
end = int(raw_input("End value of n?: "))
eqn = lambda n: raw_input("Equation?: ")
sum = 0

for i in range(start , end + 1):
    sum += eqn(i)

return sum
print summation() # start will be 1, end will be 5 , equation will be n + 1. Should print 20
```

I get the error that I can't add an integer and a string together so is there any way to make the raw_input for equation not a string. Like instead of it being 'n + 1', I want it to be n + 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use **input** instead of **raw_input**, but this isn't really a good idea, since every time **eqn** is called it will call a **input** and prompt you for the equation.

A better method is to store the equation beforehand (using **raw_input**), and then use **eval** in the lambda function. Something like:

```
def summation():
    start = int(raw_input("Start value of n?: "))
    end = int(raw_input("End value of n?: "))
    fx  = raw_input("Equation: ")
    eqn = lambda n: eval(fx)
    sum = 0

    for i in range(start , end + 1):
        sum += eqn(i)

    return sum

print summation()
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't you need to surround your raw_input in your eqn variable with an int()?
I use python 3, but that should fix your problems.